# Interpretation of Standard Deviation for different distributions

Tags: interpretation, standard-deviation

There are two different populations with unknown distributions but the standard deviation of each of them is known.
Can I conclude that the population with higher standard deviation is more spread out than the population with lower standard deviation or two population has to follow the same distribution to compare how spread out the population is.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "spread out".  A discrete random variable taking the values $\pm1$ with equal probability has standard deviation $1$, while a uniform random variable on the interval $[-1.5,1.5]$ has standard deviation about $0.866$.  The latter can be further from the mean of $0$, but also can be closer to $0$.  Standard deviation is one possible measure of dispersion (spreadoutness) but not the only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a really useful rule known as Chebychev's inequality. It states that for any distribution, you will find at least 1-1/k² observations inside k standard deviations.

This means that you are guaranteed to find 75 % of the observations inside 2 standard deviations, 88 % inside three, and so on.

So yes, your intuition is correct. The larger standard deviation means you have to account for a wider spread of values.

Comment: In the wikipedia, it says Chebyshev's inequality applies to a wide class of probability distributions. Some probability distributions do not follow it, are those distributions really rare? Thank you.

Comment: @EconomicsUser it applies to distributions that have a finite mean and variance. Critically, any real sample from any distribution will have finite variance.